# Task :app:createReleaseExpoManifest FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am trying to produce apk in a project I created with create-react-native-app. But an error like xxxx occurs. I would appreciate if anyone with knowledge helps.

Task :app:createReleaseExpoManifest FAILED
Error: Failed to connect to the packager server. If you did not start this build by running 'react-native run-android', you can start the packager manually by running 'react-native start' in the project directory. (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuhUj.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Xpf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the error message:

> Task :app:createReleaseExpoManifest FAILED
>   Error: Failed to connect to the packager server. If you did not start this build by running 'react-native run-android', you can start the packager manually by running 'react-native start' in the project directory. (Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081)

So, run `react-native start` and then build your app.

Comment: Thank you `react-native start`. While working I was able to build in another window

Comment: That doesn't work if it's running on a different IP address. `REACT_NATIVE_PACKAGER_HOSTNAME` no longer works.